# How to get product by slug with Nextjs 14 and Sanity

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity, next.js14

I'm trying to return product details by current slug that is showing in the browser.

I can return **all** the products with code below:

```
export async function getAllProducts() {
  const productData = await client.fetch('*[_type == "product"]');

  return productData;
}
```

but when I try to return the products by slug, the value returned is **null**:

```
export async function getProductBySlug(slug) {
  const currentData = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`
  );

  return currentData;
}
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By putting brackets {} around the slug param in the function name will allow for dynamic data to be transfered through it, as now the data does show and isn't null anymore.

```
export async function getProductBySlug({ slug }) {
  const currentData = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`
  );

  return currentData;
}
```